# Geoserver 2.19 ImagePyramid processing error

Tags: gdal, geoserver

I have more than 500 Gb orthophoto GTiff images with LZW compression, the task is to operate them using the geoserver's power.

The main idea is to use pyramids for much better data mobility in the future. For my tests, I use 137 Gb GTiff images with LZW compression.

Firstly, I compressed my files via GDAL util **gdal_translate**, which helps me to get 25 Gb GTiff images:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG input_file output_file
```

Secondly, I used GDAL util **gdalbuildvrt** to build a Virtual Dataset (VRT) via GDAL util **gdal_retile**:

```
gdalbuildvrt -te xmin_vrt ymin_vrt xmax_vrt ymax_vrt -srcnodata "0 0 0" output_file.vrt input_gtiff_file.tif
```

Thirdly, I used GDAL util **gdal_retile** for external pyramids building:

```
gdal_retile -of GTiff -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir C:\...\out input_file.vrt
```

All 1-4 levels have been built into 1-4 subdirectories and cuted GTiff files.

The next step was to use ImagePyramid Geoserver's extesion for 25 Gb GTiff pyramids. For correct usage, I have created a Geoserver's new data ImagePyramid Storage (ImagePyramid pyramidal plugin). Zero subdirectory has been created correctly with a ShapeFile into it.

The last step is to publish the new generated storage as a layer, but it leads the error "An error occurred while loading the page" with " Failed to load granule file" and "java.lang.NullPointerException".

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@3a4a35fe on component [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor302.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:431)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$9.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:324)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:47)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:85)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 132 more
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to create this mosaic
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:757)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.processRequest(RasterLayerResponse.java:605)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.createResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:573)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.read(RasterManager.java:1321)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:652)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:633)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.loadRequestedTiles(ImagePyramidReader.java:402)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.read(ImagePyramidReader.java:360)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:234)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:126)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getCoverageSampleDimensions(CatalogBuilder.java:1188)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverageInternal(CatalogBuilder.java:1064)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:985)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:939)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:418)
    ... 137 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleLoadingException: Failed to load granule file:/C:/AlidadA/3_software/geoserver_2_19_0/data_dir/data/1_drn_data/pyramids/out/0/8-50-0-5_epsg_4326_01_01.tif
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector.BaseSubmosaicProducer.collectGranules(BaseSubmosaicProducer.java:225)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector.BaseSubmosaicProducer.createMosaic(BaseSubmosaicProducer.java:398)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse$MosaicProducer.produce(RasterLayerResponse.java:420)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse$MosaicProducer.access$600(RasterLayerResponse.java:276)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:676)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleLoadingException: Failed to load granule file:/C:/AlidadA/3_software/geoserver_2_19_0/data_dir/data/1_drn_data/pyramids/out/0/8-50-0-5_epsg_4326_01_01.tif
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector.BaseSubmosaicProducer.collectGranules(BaseSubmosaicProducer.java:121)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleLoadingException: Failed to load granule file:/C:/AlidadA/3_software/geoserver_2_19_0/data_dir/data/1_drn_data/pyramids/out/0/8-50-0-5_epsg_4326_01_01.tif
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleLoader.call(GranuleLoader.java:112)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleLoader.call(GranuleLoader.java:38)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector.BaseSubmosaicProducer.acceptGranule(BaseSubmosaicProducer.java:445)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector.DefaultSubmosaicProducer.accept(DefaultSubmosaicProducer.java:70)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse$MosaicProducer.visit(RasterLayerResponse.java:360)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.getGranuleDescriptors(CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.java:180)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.LockingGranuleCatalog.lambda$getGranuleDescriptors$7(LockingGranuleCatalog.java:195)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.LockingGranuleCatalog.guardIO(LockingGranuleCatalog.java:93)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.LockingGranuleCatalog.getGranuleDescriptors(LockingGranuleCatalog.java:195)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.getGranuleDescriptors(RasterManager.java:1330)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:672)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleDescriptor.loadRaster(GranuleDescriptor.java:1318)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleLoader.call(GranuleLoader.java:108)
    ... 162 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in a similar situation, and I succeeded while using a GeoTIFF without any compression (especially JPEG compression). It means that I only executed your third command line :

```
gdal_retile -of GTiff -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" \
    -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir C:\...\out input_file.vrt
```

But without the `-co COMPRESS=JPEG`. And it worked ! I think it's a problem with JPEG compression, but I didn't test with others so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it worked by omitting the `COMPRESS` option. I then tried using

`-co "COMPRESS=LZW"`

and it worked. Helped me almost halving the space used by the uncompressed tiles.

Comment: What is the version of gdal do you have?

Comment: No sure. I will have to check.